# Returning local object of a primitive type and a struct

Tags: c++, reference, return-value-optimization

Getting a reference to temporary variable:

```
struct S
{
    S() = default;
    S(const S& other) = delete;
    S(S&& other) = delete;

    ~S(){}
};

S foo1()
{
    return {}; // RVO (???)
}

int foo2()
{
    return 42; // RVO
}

int main()
{
    S& i = foo1(); // compiles!
    int& i2 = foo3(); // error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'int &'
}
```

I know about reference life extension with `const` specifier. And it's clear why `foo2` gives an error. But why `foo1` works?

P.S.: tested with VS2013/15

Comment: `S& i = foo()` should not compile. `foo` returns a temporary and temporaries can't be bound to non-const references.

Comment: Funny, I think it should not compile on multiple fronts -- even if the copy ctor is never actually executed it still must be present if S is returned by value, must it not?

Comment: On the other hand the compiler is probably free to optimize the whole executable to a NOP, under the as-if rule.

Comment: Aren't you getting any compiler warnings for this?

Comment: Binding non-const lvalue reference to rvalue is illegal in standard C++. It's an infamous non-standard extension of VS.

Comment: @YamMarcovic I saw the warning only with `Level4` (/W4) option. And it says `nonstandard extension used : 'initializing' : conversion from 'S' to 'S &'`. So the question can be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiling with all warnings enabled (`/Wall`), you incidentally get the following:

> source_file.cpp(22): warning C4239: nonstandard extension used: 'initializing': conversion from 'S' to 'S &'

Answer (score 1):

gcc 4.9.3 std=c++14 doesn't like either one of the initializations.

If we change `foo1()` to

```
S foo1()
{
    S s;
    return s; 
}
```

It also complains about the deleted move ctor. I'm unsure why the original code does not need one.

[Cppreference states](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision): "Even when copy elision takes place and the copy-/move-constructor is not called, it must be present and accessible (as if no optimization happened at all), otherwise the program is ill-formed."

In the standard, 12.8/32:

> [ Note: This two-stage overload resolution must be performed regardless of whether copy elision will
>   occur. It determines the constructor to be called if elision is not performed, and **the selected constructor
>   must be accessible even if the call is elided.** —end note ]

I understand that this note refers to finding the proper move (first attempt) or copy (second attempt) constructor, not another one.

Comment: As mentioned in comments it's a nonstandard extension.

Comment: @nikitablack My wording was unclear -- I meant, why gcc (and VC++) don't need a working move ctor in order to return the temporary in the original code.

Comment: It's called Return Value Optimization (RVO or NRVO).

Comment: @nikitablack My understanding was that yes, the implementation is free to not execute the ctor (and construct the object in-place of the return value), in newer standards even violating the as-if-rule; but that nonetheless the move (or copy) ctor is required to exist and be accessible.

Comment: @nikitablack The reason for that rule is that (N)RVO is optional;another implementation (or optimzation level) may not perform it and need the ctors. If these do not exist, they probably do not exist for a reason (the reason being that these objects should not be copied around), and the implementation should respect that.

Comment: Great notice! It make sense? But as you noted (I didn't understand this note before) - move/copy constructors not required in the case of `return {};`. I don't understand - why.